# Freeze Header / Column using scrollTop / scrollLeft - corner cell

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have read a lot of freezing column / header questions but have not found anything like my problem.  This problem is best demonstrated: http://jsfiddle.net/5TYcb/4/

My problem is with the upper left corner cell "Col 1".  If I scroll up, the data in that column covers the Col 1 header.  We want the data to go under the header, not over it, just like all the other header cells.  If I scroll left, the Col 1 header disappears, I'd like it to move with the column.

Everything else about this simple scroll code works great, if only I could figure out what to do with that corner cell.

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//This code freezes the headers of the table called requestList
$(document).scroll(function () {
    if ($('#requestList').size() > 0) {
        var delta = $(window).scrollTop() - $("#requestList thead.top tr:last").offset().top;
        window.console && console.log('delta: ' + delta);
        if (delta > 0) {
            translate($("#requestList thead.top tr:last th"), 0, delta);
        } else {
            translate($("#requestList thead.top tr:last th"), 0, 0);
        };
    };

    if ($('#requestList').size() > 0) {
        var delta = $(window).scrollLeft() - $("#requestList td:nth-child(1),#HeaderRow th:nth-child(1)").offset().left;

        if (delta > 0) {
            translate($("#requestList td:nth-child(1)"), delta, 0);
        } else {
            translate($("#requestList td:nth-child(1)"), 0, 0);
        };
    };
});


function translate(element, x, y) {
    var translation = "translate(" + x + "px," + y + "px)"

        element.css({
            "transform": translation,
            "-ms-transform": translation,
            "-webkit-transform": translation,
            "-o-transform": translation,
            "-moz-transform": translation,
        });

    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<table id="requestList" class="highlighter dataTable" width="100%" style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
    <thead class="top">
        <tr role="row">
            <th colspan="14" style="background:#FFFFCC;color:black;text-align:left;">Legend: ....</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="HeaderRow" role="row">
            <th>Col 1</th>
            <th>Col 2</th>
            ....
            <th>Col 13</th>
            <th>Col 14</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="tableBodyDiv" class="reqList" role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="all">
        <tr>
            <td class="">Data 1</td>
            <td class="">Data 2</td>
            ....
            <td class="">Data 13</td>
            <td class="">Data 14</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="">Data 1</td>
            <td class="">Data 2</td>
             ...
            <td class="">Data 13</td>
            <td class="">Data 14</td>
        </tr>
        ....
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**Note:**  We've tried various fixed header plugins but they were more trouble then they were worth.  We have dynamic columns, dynamic elements above this table, etc.  We'd like to stick to this simple code which easily can be applied to any list on our site.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make css for col1 th like

```
thead th:first-child{
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}
```

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5TYcb/6/

Comment: I see in your fiddle data is now going under the col 1 header (great!), but when I scroll left the col 1 header still doesn't come along for the ride.

Comment: @vivasuzi http://jsfiddle.net/5TYcb/7/ it move now, but i didn't understand logic, does column1 data should move with column1 head?

Comment: Actually now it looks like the data in Col 1 is just disappearing when I scroll left.  What I'm looking for is that Col 1 is "frozen" like excel, including the header, when you scroll left.

Comment: @vivasuzi if understand all right then here is solution http://jsfiddle.net/5TYcb/9/

Comment: Yes!  That looks like it :)  Let me try it in my code and report back.

Comment: It works!  In my regular HTML table it worked right away.  One of mine is a datatable and the data was invisible, until I removed this part: table td{ z-index:-1;    position:relative;}  It looks like that code isn't needed because now it works fine on by tables.  Thanks!!